# Allow popups to work in Xamarin Forms WebView

Tags: xamarin.forms

This seems like a simple thing - I want to use a WebView to load / run some JavaScript from a 3rd party.

When I load the page I get a message saying "You must allow popups for this to work". I think I need to create a custom WebView (for iOS and Android!?) and I assume I need one in the shared project too?

I added this to my Android project:

```
using Android.Content;
using MyApp.Custom;
using MyApp.Droid.Custom;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid.Custom
{
    public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public CustomWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Control.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
            Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

and this to my shared project

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyKRing.Custom
{
    public class CustomWebView : WebView
    {
        
    }
}
```

and then used "CustomWebView" in my XAML.

```
<custom:CustomWebView x:Name="WebView"
                         HeightRequest="1000"
                         Source="{Binding WebViewContent}"
                         WidthRequest="1000" />
```

My TestPageViewModel has

```
        public WebViewSource WebViewContent
        {
            get => _webViewContent; 
            set => SetProperty(ref _webViewContent, value);
        }

        public TestPageViewModel()
        {
            AmountEntryFrameVisible = true;
            NuapayFrameVisible = false;

            ConfirmLoadCommand = new Command(ExecuteConfirmLoadCommand);

            var localHtml = new HtmlWebViewSource();

            localHtml.Html = @"<html>
                                   <body>
                                    <p>This is a test</p>

<script src='https://testurl.com/test.js\'></script>
<script>
    TestJS.showUI('1234567890', 'https://testurl.com/ui/');
</script>
                                    </body>
                                </html>";

            WebViewContent = localHtml;

        }
```

With the aim of making the JS run when the page is loaded by WebView.

Am I anywhere close? What is wrong with the above, as it just doesn't do anything (that ( can see).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Create the CustomWebView and create the `ShowDialog` method.**

```
 public class CustomWebView : WebView
{
    Action<string> action;

    public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Uri",
        returnType: typeof(string),
        declaringType: typeof(CustomWebView ),
        defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Uri
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
    }

    public void RegisterAction(Action<string> callback)
    {
        action = callback;
    }

    public void Cleanup()
    {
        action = null;
    }


    public void ShowDialog(string data)
    {
        if (action == null || data == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        action.Invoke(data);
    }
}
```

**2. Consume the CustomWebView**

```
   <local:CustomWebView x:Name="customWebView " Uri="index.html" />
```

**3.  Register the `ShowDiaplg` action to be invoked from JavaScript**

```
   customWebView.RegisterAction(data => DisplayAlert("Alert", DateTime.Now + "/n" + data, "OK"));
```

**4. Create the custom renderer on Android platform.**

CustomWebViewRenderer .cs:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView ), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
namespace CustomRenderer.Droid
{
public class CustomWebViewRenderer: WebViewRenderer
{
    const string JavascriptFunction = "function invokeCSharpAction(data){jsBridge2.showDialog(data);}";
    Context _context;

    public CustomWebViewRenderer (Context context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            Control.RemoveJavascriptInterface("jsBridge");
            ((CustomWebView )Element).Cleanup();
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            Control.SetWebViewClient(new JavascriptWebViewClient2(this, $"javascript: {JavascriptFunction}"));
            Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge2(this), "jsBridge2");
            Control.LoadUrl($"file:///android_asset/Content/{((CustomWebView )Element).Uri}");
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            ((CustomWebView )Element).Cleanup();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
  }
}
```

JavascriptWebViewClient2.cs:

```
public class JavascriptWebViewClient2 : FormsWebViewClient
{
    string _javascript;

    public JavascriptWebViewClient2(CustomWebViewRenderer renderer, string javascript) : base(renderer)
    {
        _javascript = javascript;
    }

    public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
    {
        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
        view.EvaluateJavascript(_javascript, null);
    }
}
```

JSBridge2.cs:

```
  public class JSBridge2 : Java.Lang.Object
{
    readonly WeakReference<CustomWebViewRenderer > hybridWebViewRenderer;

    public JSBridge2(CustomWebViewRenderer hybridRenderer)
    {
        hybridWebViewRenderer = new WeakReference<CustomWebViewRenderer >(hybridRenderer);
    }

   

    [JavascriptInterface]
    [Export("showDialog")]
    public void ShowDialog(string data)
    {
        CustomWebViewRenderer hybridRenderer;

        if (hybridWebViewRenderer != null && hybridWebViewRenderer.TryGetTarget(out hybridRenderer))
        {
            ((CustomWebView)hybridRenderer.Element).ShowDialog(data);
        }
        //string ret = "Alert  :" + DateTime.Now;

        //return ret;
    }
}
```

[image]

I followed the code sample in the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/customrenderers-hybridwebview/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It didn't 100% cater for my needs but it allowed me to get there, so thank you!